# Another way to run amd64 Docker image on Apple Silicon CPU? It won't work with Docker Desktop

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, virtualization, docker

I have written the Docker image `my-docker-img` that contains the Linux application `some-foreign-linux-app` (which was not written by me). The image is built from a [CentOS 7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) `linux/amd64` Docker image.

Unfortunately, the Docker image `my-docker-img` will not start successfully on systems with an Apple Silicon CPU. There, `some-foreign-linux-app` aborts at the startup process because the application does not detect a certain Linux kernel file. The same error occurs when `my-docker-img` is started with [`--platform linux/amd64` emulation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues) on Apple Silicon CPUs.

I suspect that it is a fruitless endeavor to try to install the Linux application `some-foreign-linux-app` inside a CentOS 7 `linux/arm64/v8` image. The application was built for Linux after all.

Is there any way other than [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/) to get my Docker image `my-docker-img` running on a MacOS computer with an Apple Silicon CPU?

Comment: You'd probably have to get qemu to emulate an x86 CPU and run an x86 linux VM in it. Then run docker under that. It would likely be slower than just buying the cheapest x86 laptop you could find.

Comment: Surely Docker containerization prevents binaries inside containers from reading Linux kernel files from the host OS? So the missing Linux kernel file must be missing from your Docker image. This problem doesn't seem likely to be caused by running on Apple silicon.

Comment: @Mokubai Doesn't Docker on Apple silicon already have qemu built-in? I'm pretty sure that's how Docker can run x86 images on Apple silicon to begin with.

Comment: @Spiff Yes, according to https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues Docker Desktop uses qemu.